# How to remove exception in Yii redis extension if one server down?

Tags: yii, redis, yii-extensions

I use php (Yii), use this extension: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rediscache/ for saving yii cache and session in redis.

I configured it to work with 2 servers.

```
'cache'=>array(                                                                  
    'class'=>'application.extensions.redis.CRedisCache',                            
    //if you dont set up the servers options it will use the default one            
    //"host=>'127.0.0.1',port=>6379"                                                
    'servers'=>array(                                                               
        array(                                                                         
            'host'=>'10.1.98.139',                                                        
            'port'=>6379,                                                                 
        ),                                                                             
        array(                                                                         
            'host'=>'10.56.192.5',                                                      
            'port'=>6379,                                                                 
        )                                                                              
    ),                                                                              
),
```

How I understand, Yii send cache and session data in both of them.

When one of them down, I need, that all users work in 1 of them, but Yii makes an Exception: **'Predis_CommunicationException' with message 'Connection refused' in /srv/www/protected/extensions/redis/Predis.php:1303**

How to fix this, and work only on one of them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far I see you need to locate the code in the extension that handles the connection section, and setup two things:

- a timeout of 1 second
- a try/catch block or other way to handle cannot connect errors.

This should be done by the extension maintainer and you, and it looks like a undocumented behavior of the extension, so make sure you submit a comment/bug ticket to that extension.

Comment: >> a timeout of 1 second
How you suppose it help?

Comment: I know that this is Bug, I interest maybe someone trying to fix it?